# Multiplying numbers in strings in C

Tags: c, string, multiplication

I wrote a function that's supposed to do that, but something in wrong with it, and I can't tell what.

main file:

```
int main()
{
    char *num1, *num2;
    num1=(char *) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
    num2=(char *) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
    mult_str(num1, num2);

    return 0;
}
```

functions:

```
    char *mult_str(char *num1, char *num2)//multiplies numbers using strings
    {
        int i, j, temp, fix1=1, fix2;
        char *result, *mult=(char *) calloc(strlen(num1)*2+1, sizeof(char));

        gets(num1);
        gets(num2);

        if(strlen(num2)>strlen(num1))//makes the longer one num1
            swapStr(&num1, &num2);

        result=(char *) calloc(strlen(num1)*2+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(result, "0");

        for(i=strlen(num2)-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
        {
            fix2=fix1;
            for(j=strlen(num1)-1 ; j>=0 ; j--)
            {
                temp=((num2[i]-'0')*(num1[j]-'0'))*fix2;
                itoa(temp, mult);
                result=add_str(result, mult);
                fix2*=10;
            }
            fix1*=10;
        }

return result
}

    char *add_str(char *num1, char *num2)//add positive numbers using strings(for big ones)
    {
        int i, s, size;
        char *sum;

        if(strlen(num2)>strlen(num1))//makes the longer one num1
            swapStr(&num1, &num2);

        size=strlen(num1)+2;
        sum=(char *) realloc(num1, size*sizeof(char));//uses num1 for the sum string
        for(i=size-2 ; i>=0 ; i--)
            sum[i+1]=sum[i];
        sum[0]='0';

        s=strlen(sum)-1;//index for sum
        for(i=strlen(num2)-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)//adds the numbers
        {
            if(sum[s]+num2[i]-2*'0'>9)//in case the sum of two numbers in bigger than 9:
            {
                sum[s-1]=sum[s-1]+(sum[s]+num2[i]-2*'0')/10;
                sum[s]=(sum[s]+num2[i]-2*'0')%10+'0';
            }
            else//in case it's not
                sum[s]=sum[s]-'0'+num2[i]-'0'+'0';
            s--;
        }

        while(sum[0]=='0')
        {
            for(i=0 ; i<size ;i++)
                sum[i]=sum[i+1];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    /* itoa:  convert n to characters in s */
    void itoa(int n, char *s)
    {
        int i, sign;

        if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
        {
            n = -n;          /* make n positive */
        }
        i = 0;
        do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
            s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
        } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
        if (sign < 0)
            s[i++] = '-';
        s[i] = '\0';
        reverse(s);
    }

    /* reverse:  reverse string s in place */
    void reverse(char *s)
    {
        int i, j;
        char c;

        for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--)
        {
            c = s[i];
            s[i] = s[j];
            s[j] = c;
        }
    }
```

Example of whats supposed to happen:
25*4=  (4*5*1)  +  (0)  +  (4*2*10)  +  (20)  =  100

What actually happens:

```
 yogev@yogev-laptop:~/question2$ ./question2//multiplying two numbers
 25
 4
 260//result
```

Comment: Don't use `strlen` that way, compute it once and store it's value.

Comment: Give us enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show the caller function

Comment: First: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: If you haven't done it yet may I refer you to The Art of Computer Programming Vol.1 Chapter 4.3.1 "The Classical Algorithms".

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `mult` goes out of scope without `free(mult);`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

```
result=(char *) calloc(strlen(num1)*2+1, sizeof(char));
result="0";
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. It's just like this:

```
i = 1;
i = 2;
```

The second line throws away the result of the first line, which means `result` winds up pointing to a static string rather than newly-allocated space. Perhaps you wanted the second line to be
`strcpy(result, "0");`
Perhaps not, it's hard to tell because your code has no comments, so there's no way to know what you're expecting it to do.

If you walk through your logic, you'll see `fix` won't always have the right value. When the outer loop repeats, `fix` needs to be 10 times what it was on the last iteration, which it will only be if the inner loop has precisely one iteration. (You should probably use two `fix` variables, one for the inner loop and one for the outer loop.)

Like this:

```
fix1=1;
for(i=strlen(num2)-1 ; i>=0 ; i--)
{
    fix2=fix1;
    for(j=strlen(num1)-1 ; j>=0 ; j--)
    {
        temp=((num2[i]-'0')*(num1[j]-'0'))*fix2;
        itoa(temp, mult);
        result=add_str(result, mult);//add_str tested and works
        fix2*=10;
    }
    fix1*=10;
}
```

I'm sure you have other bugs, but you haven't given us enough code to tell.

Comment: In addition `fix` is an `int`. I don't know your platform but even on 64-bit platforms it will overflow at 18 digits. I say this because this looks like coursework in arbitrary precision arithmetic but your use of `temp` and `fix` means you still haven't escaped the limitations of the primitive types.

Comment: @DanAllen I agree. The `fix` variable(s) should be strings as well.

Comment: Or a 'shift' register. He could 'drop' `temp` into the correct position in `mult` (zeroing the lower digits from the previous iteration). Though even then he still won't have quite implemented what Knuth describes.

Comment: @DanAllen I agree with you about the fix variables, but still, the multiplication of numeric strings is exactly where I'm stuck.
The temp variable on the otherhand, will never be more than a two figures number, so it's not necessary.

Comment: @YogevBoaron Well, multiplying by 10 is especially easy. ;)

Comment: @YogevBoaron temp will never be more than 2 non-zero digits. However you are multiplying it by fix2 which will eventually be twice the scale of the inputs. You will overflow multiplying two 10 digit numbers. If you wrote a little function with prototype char* add_short(char* add,unsigned short digits,unsigned short exp); that calculates add+dights*pow(10,exp) without overflow you're basically home and only need one result array. NB: I notice your representation is big-endian which (obviously) suits print-out. It would more efficient in arithmetic if it were little-endian.

Comment: You could even use your `reverse(.)` function again. Calculate the multiplication result in little-endian and reverse it at the end.